# Listening to many Kafka Streams in Spring

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm developing an application in the event-driven architecture.

I'm trying to model the following flow of events:

UserAccountCreated (user-management-events) -> sending an e-mail -> MailNotificationSent (notification-service-events)

The **notification-service** application executes the whole flow. It waits for the **UserAccountCreated** event by listening to *user-management-events* topic. When the event is received, the application sends the email and publishes a new event - **MailNotificationSent** to the *notification-service-events* topic.

I have no problems with listening to the first event (**UserAccountCreated**) - application receives it and performs the rest of the flow. I also have no problem with publishing the **MailNotificationSent** event. Unfortunately, for development purposes, I want to listen to the **MailNotificationSent** event in the notification service, so the application has to listen to both **UserAccountCreated** and **MailNotificationSent**. Here I'm not able to make it works.

Let's take a look at the implementation:

NotificationStreams:

```
public interface NotificationStreams {

    String INPUT = "notification-service-events-in";
    String OUTPUT = "notification-service-events-out";

    @Input(INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel inboundEvents();

    @Output(OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel outboundEvents();
}
```

NotificationsEventsListener:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NotificationEventsListener {


    @StreamListener(NotificationStreams.INPUT)
    public void notificationServiceEventsIn(Flux<ActivationLinkSent> input) {
        input.subscribe(event -> {
            log.info("Received event ActivationLinkSent: " + event.toString());
        });
    }
}
```

UserManagementEvents:

```
public interface UserManagementEvents {

    String INPUT = "user-management-events";

    @Input(INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel inboundEvents();
}
```

UserManagementEventsListener:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserManagementEventsListener {

    private final Gate gate;

    @StreamListener(UserManagementEvents.INPUT)
    public void userManagementEvents(Flux<UserAccountCreated> input) {
        input.subscribe(event -> {
            log.info("Received event UserAccountCreated: " + event.toString());
            gate.dispatch(SendActivationLink.builder()
                .email(event.getEmail())
                .username(event.getUsername())
                .build()
            );
        });
    }
}
```

KafkaStreamsConfig:

```
@EnableBinding(value = {NotificationStreams.class, UserManagementEvents.class})
public class KafkaStreamsConfig {
}
```

EventPublisher:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class EventPublisher {

    private final NotificationStreams eventsStreams;

    private final AvroMessageBuilder messageBuilder;

    public void publish(Event event) {
        MessageChannel messageChannel = eventsStreams.outboundEvents();

        AvroActivationLinkSent activationLinkSent = new AvroActivationLinkSent();                         activationLinkSent.setEmail(((ActivationLinkSent)event).getEmail());
        activationLinkSent.setUsername(((ActivationLinkSent)event).getUsername() + "-domain");
        activationLinkSent.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        messageChannel.send(messageBuilder.buildMessage(activationLinkSent));
    }
}
```

application config:

```
spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: true
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        contentType: application/*+avro
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
      schemaRegistryClient:
        endpoint: http://localhost:8990
  kafka:
    consumer:
      group-id: notification-group
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
kafka:
  bootstrap:
    servers: localhost:9092
```

The application seems to ignore the notification-service-events listener. It works when listening to only one stream.

I'm almost 100% sure that this is not an issue with publishing the event, because I've connected manually to Kafka and verified that messages are published properly:

```
kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic notification-service-events-out --from-beginning
```

Do you have any ideas what else I should check? Is there any additional configuration on the Spring side?

Answer (score 0):

I've found where the problem was.
I was missing bindings configuration. In the application properties, I should have added the following lines:

```
cloud:
 stream:
  bindings:
    notification-service-events-in:
      destination: notification-service-events
    notification-service-events-out:
      destination: notification-service-events
    user-management-events-in:
      destination: user-management-events
```

In the user-management-service I didn't have such a problem because I used a different property:

```
  cloud:
   stream:
    default:
      contentType: application/*+avro
      destination: user-management-events
```